# While in virtualenv I'm getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rets.client'; 'rets' is not a package"

Tags: python-3.x, import, module, pip, package

I am implementing a script that I wrote in PyCharm a few weeks back, but when I run it on a virtual environment on my server using `python3 -m venv myvenv` (and of course using pip3 while running my venv to install packages) it gives me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rets.client'; 'rets' is not a package error.`

I've reinstalled the package. I've recreated my venv. I've made sure that my python3 path is referencing the correct python3.exe in my venv directory (same thing for pip3). I've checked that there is no PATH being set in my .bashrc file that might cause issues.

This is how the package has me importing...

```
import mysql.connector
from tqdm import tqdm
from rets.client import RetsClient #This one here
```

When I run `print(sys.path)` I get this result:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/root/retsvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

I had this working a few weeks ago in PyCharm but now that I'm trying to deploy it in a virtual environment it just doesn't seem to find that package.

Comment: Do you have a script called `rets.py`?

Comment: Biggest face palm moment of my life right there. That's exactly what it was. Thank you!

Comment: A known problem in Python: never name your scripts the way them overshadow existing modules/packages. Especially forbidden are `email.py` and `test.py`. :-)